# (Survival Salt) Extract Salt from natural sorces (In the wild) without the Ocean

Tags: salt, storage

I'm inquiring to learn a survival technique in the wilderness.  How can I extract and crystallize salt (sodium chloride) from wild plants, animals, or rocks, with access to a freshwater source only. I imagine soaking smoked meat to make a broth and letting it evaporate and crystallize, or steaming vegetables and again dehydrating a broth. Any insight will assist.

Comment: This may be a better fit for the [outdoors stackexchange](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @mattm - it might be on topic or a better fit there, but I think we do have some questions about foraging or wild-sourcing ingredients on this site, so it may not be off-topic here

Comment: From animals?  Easy, just collect your perspiration.

Comment: Thank you for the great comments and suggestions! I'll look into all possibilities. Don't limit your knowledge to my local. However, I am looking for something specifically in the Southwest of the USA. The primary trees around are Maraposa Pine, Aspin, Mesquite and Palo Verede. Sweat isn't something I had thought of but that is a something we get a lot of here lol. Roots or Branches sounds promising. We also have a large selection of Cactus.

Answer (score 1):

One option I know of is hickory salt, also found as hickory tree salt or hickory root salt.  (not to be confused with hickory smoked salts, which does require salt to make)

Hickory salt is made by digging up the roots of hickory trees, shredding them, and boiling them to a dry, black, salty and mineralish powder.  You *may* be able to get salt from hickory limbs, I saw a [reference](http://discuss.rewild.com/t/salt-from-hickory-trees/1915) but only one, so no guarantees.

One recipe is [here](https://www.survival-manual.com/hickory-salt.php), another is [there](http://bladesandbushlore.com/index.php?topic=6053.0)

Hickory seems the best bet (for me, anyway, for volume acquirable per plant, identifiability, local to my area etc)

However, it seems there are some other plants that can yield salt - including a [source](https://practicalselfreliance.com/coltsfoot-salt/) citing coltsfoot, and (having heard of) wild parsnip or wild carrot roots, or stinging nettles, but that source has no experience with either.

Lambs's quarters is another potential source - it's in the comments of the coltsfoot source, and mentioned [here](https://www.motherearthnews.com/real-food/seasonal-recipes/lambsquarter-ze0z1412zcgp) (as having mineral salts, not really "extracting them as salt source")

Another possibility is called [saltbush](https://www.sbs.com.au/food/article/2017/11/16/pass-saltbush-one-australias-best-herbs), which is apparently used as a salty seasoning in [australia](https://keys.lucidcentral.org/keys/v3/pastures/Html/Old_man_saltbush.htm).

Many of these sources are assuming a survival knowledge context, so these sources may be what you're looking for.

And of course it may be possible to find mineral salt deposits, from salty or brackish water or animal salt licks... this would involve observing larger animals (like deer, for example) to see where they're getting their salt from... it is essential for life for them as well.

It may, potentially, be possible to source salts from animal sources, since they must be sourcing salt somewhere, but I don't know anything about that or how to tell if any such preparation has it in sufficient quantities or whatever (vs perhaps other undesirable salts or mineral concentrations).  Sorry.